# Change the active project in Eclipse - SVN Synchronize

Tags: eclipse, svn, synchronize

When I want to synchronize (svn) a project in Eclipse, I choose 'Team - Synchronize with repository' in the project explorer. The perspective then changes to Team Synchronizing.

Sometimes I need to update/synchronize another project as well.

Is there a fast way to change the active project in the Synchronize perspective, so I don't have to go back first to the other perspective with the php explorer on it?

Why doesn't the synchronize dropdown show all other svn repositories that I have defined??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution that works. I enabled the PHP explorer  (or project explorer) in the Synchronize perspective, so i can switch projects on that perspective without having to go back.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know of a way to change projects from the Synchronize perspective, but you can try this instead:

Select multiple projects in the explorer view and right click and select **Team -> Synchronize**. Now all the projects you selected will be shown in the Synchronize window. From there you can commit and update changes on a per-project basis, or commit changes across multiple projects.